# Disable/Enable Button

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a submit button for my form in my PHP file like below.

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" disabled="true" />
```

now i send an asynchronous request using a request object,

```
document.getElementById("username").onblur=function(){ 
username(this.value);
 };

function username(value)
{
request = createRequest();
if(request==null) {
alert("Unable to create request");
return;
}
var url= "sign_up.php?value=" +
escape(value);
request.open("GET",url,true);
request.onreadystatechange = displayDetails;
request.send(null);
}
function displayDetails() {
if (request.readyState == 4) {
if (request.status == 200) {
checked = document.getElementById("check");
checked.innerHTML = request.responseText;
document.getElementById("submit").disabled="false";
}
}
}
```

here it basically is checking the availability of a username, now i enable the submit button,if a username enteres is available. But it really is not enabling the button. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: please check whether the ready state is 4 or not

Comment: Have you checked the firebug?

Comment: Can you please verify if the innerHTML of "check" element is getting updated with the reponseText? This is done just before enabling the submit button. If it is updated then we need to see your HTML. Please post the HTML snippet.

Comment: is there a reason you're not using a library such as jquery? This could all be easily done in a few lines...

Comment: @ilia choly- the reason is that i dont know anything about library such as jquery yet.! still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the quotation marks, what you did was assigning a string "false" into the `disabled` attribute of the HTML element. Change the last line to this:

```
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable:

```
document.getElementById("submit").setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Enable:

```
document.getElementById("submit").removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery verison

```
$("#username").blur(function(){
    $("#submit").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        url: "sign_up.php",
        data: {
            cmd: "check_username",
            value: $(this).val()
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#check").html(data);
            $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        },
        error: function(){
            $("#check").html("ajax error");
            $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but i really dint understand anything as i am not failiar with jquery. just out of curiosity, what really is jquery?